# php converting date to int whole numbers

Tags: php

So let's say that I have a bunch of variables and I want to convert them into something completly else.

```
<?php
    $date1 = "02:00:00";
    $date2 = "2021-03-11 12:10:00";
    $date3 = "2021-03-11 16:32:00";
    // I want date1 to look like ->  200(int)
    // I want date2 to look like -> 1210(int)
    // I want date3 to look like -> 1632(int)
?>
```

Can this be accomplished?

EDITED

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? What are the rules of the conversion? Currently, it seems as though you'd like to have the hours and minutes expressed as an integer, but the third example doesn't coincide with this. Also, what would be the purpose of this integer representation?

Comment: My bad it was a typo. 
The int representation is only for further calculations.

Comment: Are they time calculations? Because this would seem a bad choice for such things.

Comment: If you want to use integers to represent time then Unix timestamps are a well established standard convention for doing this, and are understood by PHP's date and time functions already. No need to invent your own system, IMO